# HtmlPage deserialization in Java - ClassNotFound Error

Tags: java, serialization, htmlunit

I have some troubles deserializing Htmlpage from a HtmlUnit java package.

## TL;DR

The error I get (happens on line `Object o = in.readObject();`):

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.util.Cookie
```

Full stack trace: http://pastebin.com/geH7SgWu

### Question

What might be the cause of this problem? Am I missing something or is the SVN code flawed ?

---

**The code I use:**

*Serialization:*

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutput out = null;

try {
  out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
  out.writeObject(this.htmlPage);
} catch (Exception ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
} finally {
  out.close();
  bos.close();
}
return bos.toByteArray();
```

*Deserialization:*

```
ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(content.getContent());
ObjectInput in = null;
HtmlPage htmlPage2 = null;

try {
  in = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
  Object o = in.readObject();
  htmlPage2 = (HtmlPage) o;
} catch (Exception ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
} finally {
  bis.close();
  in.close();
}
```

Serialized object is sent as bytes in `content` variable ([Protocol plugin](http://nutch.apache.org/apidocs-1.4/org/apache/nutch/protocol/http/api/HttpBase.html#getResponse) in Nutch). It is then received using `content.getContent()` method (this happens in [Parsing plugin](http://nutch.apache.org/apidocs-1.4/org/apache/nutch/protocol/Content.html#getContent%28%29) in Nutch).

---

I have all the dependencies of HtmlUnit and HtmlUnit itself accessible from code.

What is weird is that I don't even use the `Cookie` class anywhere. Later, for testing purposes, I have created a Cookie and it all went well.

I have verified that it is contained in one of the jars:

```
$ jar -tf htmlunit-2.11-SNAPSHOT.jar | grep Cookie
com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/HtmlUnitCookieStore.class

com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/util/Cookie.class

com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/HtmlUnitBrowserCompatCookieSpec.class
com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/HtmlUnitBrowserCompatCookieSpec$2.class
com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/CookieManager.class
com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/HtmlUnitBrowserCompatCookieSpec$1.class
com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/HtmlUnitBrowserCompatCookieSpec$3.class
```

---

### Versions:

**JARs visible:**

```
commons-codec-1.6.jar
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
commons-io-2.4.jar
commons-lang3-3.1.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
cssparser-0.9.7.jar
htmlunit-2.11-SNAPSHOT.jar
htmlunit-core-js-2.11-20120814.002723-22.jar
httpclient-4.2.1.jar
httpcore-4.2.1.jar
httpmime-4.2.1.jar
jetty-http-8.1.5.v20120716.jar
jetty-io-8.1.5.v20120716.jar
jetty-util-8.1.5.v20120716.jar
jetty-websocket-8.1.5.v20120716.jar
nekohtml-1.9.16.jar
sac-1.3.jar
serializer-2.7.1.jar
xalan-2.7.1.jar
xercesImpl-2.10.0.jar
xml-apis-1.4.01.jar
```

**HtmlUnit** - SVN Snapshot on 10.09.2012 compiled by following this short tutorial http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingLatestCode.html

**Nutch 1.4**

---

I hope the information I have supplied is enough. If not, please let me know in the comments and I'll be happy to update the question.

Thanks in advance and regards,

szalski

Answer (score 0):

According to grepcode.com `com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.util.Cookie` is present in the following versions of htmlunit: 2.9, 2.8, 2.7.

Try using htmunit v2.9 for example. Might be that some jars in your classpath are looking for a particular version of htmlunit

Comment: Tried HtmlUnit 2.9 and it doesn't contain CHROME_16 browser version and I cannot even log in on a particular site.

Tried HtmlUnit 2.10 and got the following error: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't find top level scope for ClassCache.get`

Btw, Cookie is also in the official APIDocs for 2.10: http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/util/Cookie.html

Comment: checked in the project SVN repo, Cookie class is present. So my assumption that the class is missing in the jar is wrong. :(